# Angularjs. Как сделать сплывающее окно с редактором параметров объекта из списка?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Привет всем!
Изучаю angularjs, пишу проект с его использованием.

В общем, суть такова. Имеется таблица с определенного рода объектами, отображаемыми в этой таблице. Таблица строится с помощью angularjs.

В каждой строке хочу добавить кнопку, по нажатию на которую должно всплывать окно, в котором будут доступны для редактирования параметры конкретного объекта.

Использую twitter bootstrap для создания интерфейса, модальное окошко хочу использовать из этого фреймворка.

На хабре читал статью, в которой описывается создание админки, но она мне не подходит, т.к. при редактировании записи, форма для редактирования заменяет собой таблицу с объектами.

Помогите пожалуйста понять, с какой стороны нужно подойти к этой проблеме?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже смотрели [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)?

Comment: Спасибо. Забавно, но Я использовал AngularStrap, в нем было что-то подобное. но в UI Bootstrap то-же самое сделано симпатичнее, в итоге переделал все на указанной вами библиотеке. Работает)